# Searching through ListView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've read through the [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) and through [react native express](http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/).

I'm trying to learn react native trough experience and building apps.

My current issue happens after I created an static ListView and try to filter through it. I've found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938189/search-data-in-listview-react-native) of how another was able to achieve it, but I get the error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.rows.length')

I though `rows` was defined in:

```
    state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows)
  }
```

So I'm confused to where the error comes from.

**app file**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { 
    AppRegistry,
    ListView, 
    View, 
    Text, 
    StyleSheet, 
    Image, 
    Button, 
    TouchableOpacity, 
    TextInput, 
    ScrollView,
    Icon,
} from 'react-native';

import { createStackNavigator, } from 'react-navigation';

const image1 = require('./assets/card-0.png')
const image2 = require('./assets/card-2.png')
const image3 = require('./assets/card-3.png')
const image4 = require('./assets/card-4.png')
const image5 = require('./assets/card-5.png')

// Row data (hard-coded)
const rows = [
  {id: 0, club: 'Club Air', genre: 'Hip Hop / R&B', image: image1},
  {id: 1, club: 'Abe', genre: 'Hip Hop / R&B', image: image2},
  {id: 2, club: 'John Doe', genre: 'Hip Hop / R&B', image: image3},
  {id: 3, club: 'Encore', genre: 'Hip Hop / R&B', image: image4},
  {id: 4, club: 'Jimmy Whoo', genre: 'Hip Hop / R&B', image: image5},
]

// Row comparison function
const rowHasChanged = (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id

// DataSource template object
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged})

export class HomeScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        // title: ' Alpha',
        header: null,
    };

  state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows)
  }

  setSearchText(event){
    const searchText = event.nativeEvent.text;

    clubsLength = this.state.rows.length;
    aClub= this.state.rows;

    const filteredClubs = this.state.rows.filter(checkTitle);
    console.log("clubs: " + JSON.stringify(filteredClubs));

    function checkClub() {
        for(i=0;i<clubsLength;i++){
          if(aClub[i].club === searchText){
            console.log("found:  " + aClub[i].club);
            return aClub[i];
          }
        }
    }

    this.setState({
        searchText,
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(filteredClubs),
    });
  }

  renderRow = (rowData) => { 
    return (

        <View style={styles.card}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}> 
                <View style={styles.innerCard}>
                    <Image 
                        style={styles.imageCard} 
                        source={rowData.image}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.innerText}>
                        {rowData.club}
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.outerCard}>
                    <Text style={styles.outerText}>
                        {rowData.genre}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.outerTexts}>
                       View
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
  }


  render() {
    return (

        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.SearchBarContainer}>
                <TextInput  
                placeholder="Search"
                value={this.state.searchText}
                onChange={this.setSearchText.bind(this)}
                style={styles.searchBar}
                underlineColorAndroid="#DD016B"
                selectionColor="#DD016B"
                />
            </View>
            <ListView
            style={styles.listContainer}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
            />
        </ScrollView>

    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    width:'100%',
    // height: 299,

  },
  SearchBarContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  listContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    width:'100%',
    // height: 299,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    width: '50%',
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 30,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#DD016B',
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  searchBar: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    height: 40, 
    width:200,
    color: '#DD016B',
    borderColor: '#DD016B', 
    // selectionColor: '#DD016B',
    // borderWidth: 1,
    // borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom:20,
    marginTop: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  card: {
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  innerCard: {
    height:110,
  },
  imageCard: {
    width: 500,
    height: 150,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0, 
    marginBottom:0, 
    marginTop: 0,
  },
  innerText: {
    color: 'white',
    marginBottom: 0,
    fontSize: 35,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 100,
  },
  outerText: {
    color: '#DD016B',
    marginBottom: 0,
    marginTop: 50,
    width: 100,
  },
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)

export default createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
});
```

Comment: Your `HomeScreen` component doesn't have `rows` in its state.

Comment: @Tholle Could you care to explain to me, or where I can find it explained how to do this?

Comment: You have your `rows` array as a variable outside of your component. If you want it in your state you can write e.g. `state = { dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows), rows }` or reference `rows` instead of `this.state.rows`.

Comment: @Tholle , that seemed to have helped. It seems the app searches but can't find the title, but i'll keep troubleshooting and looking trough the docs. You can post it as an answer so I can close this question. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get your error is because you are trying to read `rows` from your state, but `rows` is an array outside of your component.

You could either reference the `rows` array that is outside of your state, or put the array in state when you create it.

**Example**

```js
export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

  state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows),
    rows
  };

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why I dont get any results when I search? Example : club air. I just get an empty screen.

Comment: @Salman I'm not quite sure. It might be worth creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and create a new question with that.

Comment: Thanks CodeSandbox seems very useful! I'll see if i can trouble shoot it